# Game sharing question

Tags: ps4, psn

Scenario - I have bought a digital copy of a game via the PS Store. My brother has had access to my account and download the game so that he can play it (Told him not too)

I have changed my password for my PSN account now.

Question: Can he still play the game he downloaded from my account?
Question: If yes, how can I prevent him from playing it?

Comment: By not giving him the password in the first place? A download is downloaded, usually that means that it can be played whenever you want to, but I don't know if there maybe is some PS4 feature that prevents it. Which game is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share games between two playstation 4's all the time.

This is how it works and it all depends on which playstation is your primary one.

If your brother plays on a playstation which is the primary playstation for your account then he can play without you being logged in.

If your brother is on a playstation that is not set as your primary then you need to be logged in for him to play the game.

If you are sharing one playstation and it is set as the primary for your account then he can play any game you have downloaded. Likewise if the playstation is also his primary then you can play anything he has purchased and downloaded. The fact he can play the game will have no effect on your account.

You cant block this if you are sharing the same playstation unless you remove the game when you are done and make it so he can not use your account (require password each time you login).

Answer (score 0):

While Kenjara is correct, if he is using a separate PS4 you have one more options.

Log into your account via the web (can't do it via the PS4) and "unauthorize" all devices. This effectively tells PSN that you don't use this machine any more and any games on there will stop working.

Now log into your personal PS4 and re-authorize your specific device. You may also need to restore licenses on your machine to get everything you've already downloaded working again.

[How to Restore Licenses](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/license.html)

**And stop sharing your password**